# Grep pattern that has double quotes and variable substitution surrounded by single quotes

Tags: grep, quoting, variable-substitution, pattern-matching

So, Let's say I have the following pattern:

```
Thisisatest="1"
```

in a file called `file`.

And I want to match the *exact* string above *but* for whatever reason, I choose to loop over some numbers from a list, use those as variable and try to do this:

```
Thisisatest="$varhere"
```

Where the above `$varhere` is equal to the number above, being `1`. (while i mentioned looping over number, *this* was just a future possible use cases for this and remain an example)

Now to make things easier, say I want to match the above *exact* pattern *while* using the above variable and it's content:

```
grep 'Thisisatest="$varhere"' file
```

Where file contain the string `Thisisatest="1"` and `$varhere` contain the number `1`.

Problem being, this wouldn't work *because* variable expansion doesn't occur when in-between single quotes (like above).

Here the failed attempt at countering this:

1. substitution of content from variable substitution

```
echo "${varhere/[0-9]*/Thisisatest=\"$varhere\"}"
```

Here I use `echo` to see if it output the *right* string so it can be used as input for grep...it output this instead:

```
'Thisisatest="'1'"
```

2. Add more quotes

```
echo "'Thisisatest="${varhere}"'"
```

output:

```
'Thisisatest='1''
```

```
echo ''''Thisisatest=\"${varhere}\"''''
```

output:

```
Thisisatest="'1'"
```

The rest is obvious...
Now the very last attempt above seems to be close to what i want, but still not it.

Any way(s) to do the above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
grep "Thisisatest=\"${varhere}\""
```

works for me. "`\`" flips the "I am a special character" flag of the following character through ONE shell interpretation.

Comment: This works! I did try to escape some of the double quote in other attempt, but didn't come up with *this* one as you did. :)

Comment: Any advantage with `\"${x}\""` over `\"$x\""` ?

Comment: Not in this case.   But if you  $x = y  and you want y1  then ${x}1  is the best way to get it.  $x1 will instead look for variable $x1

Comment: @user10489: Yes. If one have a alpha-numeric following the variable it is obviously the best way, I simply wondered if there is any quirks to it beyond that.

Comment: It's not a bad habit to always isolate variables like that.

Comment: Indeed, that's why I did it in the first place :) @user10489